# How to change appearance of a particular line when using \lstincludelisting?

Tags: listings, formatting, include

I'm using the `listings` package and include code into my document through `\lstincludelistings`. The problem is that I want to set some code lines to bold to indicate changes from previous code segments.

How can I achieve this without having to copy-paste the code directly into the document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution would be to define a macro that invokes `\lstinputlisting` three times (for the part before the line to emphasize, the line itself, and the part after the line to emphasize) and adopts the listing style with `\lstset` to achive the desired highlighting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor}   % for coloring as emph
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifnumcomp
\usepackage{beramono} % a tt font that has a boldface series

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

% The style to be applied for the highlighted line:
\lstdefinestyle{highlight}{basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{red}}
%\lstdefinestyle{highlight}{backgroundcolor=\color{orange!30}}

% input listing and emphasize a specific line
% \lstinputemph[listings options]{line number}{filename}
\newcommand{\lstinputemph}[3][\empty]{%                                                    
 \lstset{aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt, showlines=true,#1}%
 \ifnumcomp{#2}{=}{0}{\lstinputlisting{#3}}{%
   \ifnumcomp{#2}{=}{1}{}{\lstinputlisting[lastline=\the\numexpr#2-1\relax]{#3}}%            
   \lstinputlisting[firstnumber={#2},firstline={#2},lastline={#2},style=highlight]{#3}
   \lstinputlisting[firstnumber={\the\numexpr#2+1},firstline=\the\numexpr#2+1\relax]{#3}
 }% else
}

\begin{document}
  \lstinputemph[language=C]{3}{hello.c}
\end{document}
```

With file `hello.c` as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  printf("Hello, World\n")
}
```

This lead to the following output (second example uses a different background color for the highlighting effect)

[image: Example Output 1]

[image: Example Output 2]

Comment: That's quite nifty! But what if I want to emphasize more than one line?

Comment: @gablin: Then you should probably rephrase the title of your question ;-) No, seriously: (1) Do you need to just give a (e.g. comma-separated) list of lines (like 1,5,6,7,12) or do you also need ranges (like 1,5-7,12) (2) Do you insist on a font change to highlight the lines or would a different background color (as in my second example) be suitable.

Comment: Hm, yeah that would make it much harder. I actually ended up not emphasizing any lines at all, but you did answer my question so I'll accept your answer.