# Passing optional arguments to a listing environment based on conditionals

Tags: listings, conditionals, optional-arguments

I am trying to make a presentation which can optionally compiled for handouts. This presentation also contains highlighted code snippets. For highlighting I use the code from [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30877/highlighting-line-ranges-in-a-lstlisting-partial-solution-but-expansion-issues) (Which works fine in my real presentation, however produces highlights too far to the right in the minimal examples.)

When I compile for handout mode, the last of the highlighted lines is still present in the listing. Therefore I am looking for some way to conditionally disable the highlighting.

What I have so far:

The conditional:

```
\newif\ifhandout
\handouttrue
\ifhandout
   \documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\else
  \documentclass{beamer}
\fi
```

The highlighting:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{ListingTest}
  \begin{lstlisting}[linebackgroundcolor={
    \btLstHL<1>{1-3}
    \btLstHL<2>{6,9}
    }]
    ... some code thats at least 9 lines long
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

The problem now is, that I don't know how I achieve optional compilation of the optional `linebackground` argument. An additional problem is that I have to escape commands inside the listing environmt. I have tried placing `if`s at various locations like:

```
\ifhandout
\begin{lstlisting}
(*@\else
\begin{lstlisting}[linebackgroundcolor={
  \btLstHL<1>{1-3}
  \btLstHL<2>{6,9}
  }](*@\fi@*)
    ... code
\end{lstlisting}
```

But nothing worked as expected. (I even managed to place them in a way that collapsed all code in the listing in a single line.)

Does someone know, how I can exclude the argument in `[]` from compilation when `handout` ist `true`?

Here is the complete "minimal" example for testing. Thank you very much in advance.

```
\newif\ifhandout

\handouttrue

\ifhandout
    \documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\else
    \documentclass{beamer}
\fi

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgf, pgffor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\lstset
{
    inputencoding=utf8,
    language=c++,
    basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=5pt,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    showstringspaces=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    frame=single,
    tabsize=4,
    morekeywords={decltype},
    literate={ö}{{\"o}}1
           {ä}{{\"a}}1
           {ü}{{\"u}}1
           {Ä}{{\"A}}1
           {Ö}{{\"O}}1
           {Ü}{{\"U}}1
           {ß}{{\ss}}1
           {~}{{\textasciitilde}}1
}

\lstloadlanguages{C++}

% Some Code copied from stackoverflow for highlighting

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% \btIfInRange{number}{range list}{TRUE}{FALSE}
%
% Test in int number <number> is element of a (comma separated) list of ranges
% (such as: {1,3-5,7,10-12,14}) and processes <TRUE> or <FALSE> respectively

\newcount\bt@rangea
\newcount\bt@rangeb

\newcommand\btIfInRange[2]{%
    \global\let\bt@inrange\@secondoftwo%
    \edef\bt@rangelist{#2}%
    \foreach \range in \bt@rangelist {%
        \afterassignment\bt@getrangeb%
        \bt@rangea=0\range\relax%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{ ( #1 >= \bt@rangea) && (#1 <= \bt@rangeb) }%
        \ifnum\result=1\relax%
            \breakforeach%
            \global\let\bt@inrange\@firstoftwo%
        \fi%
    }%
    \bt@inrange%
}
\newcommand\bt@getrangeb{%
    \@ifnextchar\relax%
        {\bt@rangeb=\bt@rangea}%
        {\@getrangeb}%
}
\def\@getrangeb-#1\relax{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \bt@rangeb=100000%   \maxdimen is too large for pgfmath
    \else%
        \bt@rangeb=#1\relax%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand<>{\btLstHL}[1]{%
  \only#2{\btIfInRange{\value{lstnumber}}{#1}{\color{blue!30}\def\lst@linebgrdcmd{\color@block}}{\def\lst@linebgrdcmd####1####2####3{}}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{ListingTest}
  \begin{lstlisting}[linebackgroundcolor={
      \btLstHL<1>{1-3}
      \btLstHL<2>{6,9}
      \btLstHL<3>{7}
      \btLstHL<4>{8}
    }]
        /**
         * Prints Hello World.
         **/
        #include <stdio.h>

        int main(void) {
           printf("Hello World!");  
           return 0;
        }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Isn't this much easier with `\mode<handout>...` to select the relevant content for the presentation and the handout separately?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the welcome and the hint - I did not know that this exists. However, I am not entirely sure how to use this directive with the listings environment. I tried to either place only the square brackets or the entire `\begin{lstlisting}[...]` in a `mode` but it didn't work. I would not really like to duplicate everything between `begin`and `end`.